# jQuery slimScroll plugin doesn't include indents inside child node

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slimscroll

jQuery slimScroll plugin after initialization doesn't take into account while calculates slimScrollDiv height. So, there's parent height less than real child's height. Difference is accurate equal to height of vertical margin and horizontal border width in child block. Therefore, scrollbar is always visible. Need to avoid this.

```
.parent(ref="dropdownScroll")
  .child
    ul
      li
```

```
window.$(this.$refs.dropdownScroll).slimScroll({
   height: 'auto',
   railVisible: true,
   size: '12px',
   color: '#ccc',
   railColor: '#fff',
   railOpacity: 1,
});
```

```
.child
  margin-bottom 30px
  border 1px solid black
```

So, child is scrolling, even if no reason for it.

Comment: I don't know how it works, but replace margin-top instead margin-bottom has handled this issue. There's a few children and everything is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how it works, but replace margin-top instead margin-bottom has handled this issue. There's a few children and everything is ok